# What is the name of the song that plays at ~7:25 in Episode 18 of Try?

Tags: music, gundam-build-fighters

I've listened through the OST for Gundam Build Fighters Try (ala YouTube), to find this particular song sequence. However, none of the tracks have this bgm, nor seem like an original of the bgm. Does someone know what other bgm track this could be from?

It's in Episode 18, and starts at around 7:25 (Just after Sekai breaks out of an energy net).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcyas4ux6ho

Comment: You don't need to include the series title in the title of your question. You just need to make a more descriptive one.

Comment: No series name? Then you'd need to enter the post to see the full name right?

Comment: The tag is intended be the main differentiator. Currently we're having a discussion in our meta about how to handle manga of different continuities and spinoffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jumped the Gun(dam) here. Show finished Airing 4/2015, and looked for OST around then. OST was released in Dec-2014. However in 2015, a Second OST was released. Found the track: "New Dimension Overlord Flow".
Interesting that the 2nd OST isn't listed on Gundam Wikia.